# Is a fee note the same as an invoice?

Tags: united-kingdom, accounting, fees

I pay an accountant £800 a year to do the usual accountancy things.

I've received a fee note from him for filing the annual confirmation statement.

So, is a fee note the same as an invoice? Do I need to pay this or is it just a casual reminder that he's there, doing my accounts?

Just to note: it doesn't include an invoice number and has been printed on peach coloured paper, which makes me think it's more of a reminder or is part of the annual fee... but their bank account details have been included which makes me think they're after payment.

Comment: Check out here. http://www.accountingweb.co.uk/any-answers/invoice-or-fee-note Doesn't make much of a difference to you.

Comment: So do I need to pay the fee or is it included in the annual invoice?

Comment: Can you ask your accountant to clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fee note is the same as an invoice.

There are VAT reasons behind issuing a fee note, but from the receivers perspective, it still needs to be paid in the same way as you'd pay an invoice.